# TikZ: double line: rasterisation issue

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some issues with the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{every matrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,row sep=3.5em,column sep=3.5em}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m){
        A & A\\
        A & A\\
}; \path
    (m-1-1) edge[double distance=2pt] (m-1-2)
    (m-1-1) edge[double distance=2pt] (m-2-1)
    (m-2-1) edge[double distance=2pt] (m-2-2)
    (m-1-2) edge[double distance=2pt] (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Depending on the zoom setting of my PDF viewer (Okular), the result can be quite ugly (zoom level 300%):

[image: Okular Example]

(Printing though is fine.) I am a bit worried as an unsuspecting person could misread/misunderstand the diagram. Is this a widespread issue or just an Okular bug? Is there any known solution?

Comment: OK, as this seems to be an Okular-only bug, I am going to write a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of okular. Try with evince, and you'll see a better result. I'm not aware of any workaround for that, unfortunately :(

Edit: According to the docs, there [is an option to tinker with antialiasing](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdegraphics/okular/configperformance.html). I have an older version, so I can't test that, maybe it works for you?

Comment: No, turning off anti-aliasing unfortunately doesn't improve the output.